# What logical differences are between "if" in conditional clauses and "provided that" in proviso clauses?

Tags: logic, semantics

In Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> The conjunction dum, sometimes strengthened by the adverb modo, "only", may introduce a subordinate clause stating a provision under which the event of the main clause can occur. Such a clause is called a proviso clause.

In a conditional sentence, the conditional clause

> states the condition that must occur in order for the main clause to occur.

and is introduced by si or nisi.

My questions are:

- What are the differences between conditional and [proviso clauses](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Estruck/classes/latin309/syntax/proviso.html)? How different are they in terms of logic (not just Latin)?
- Can a conjunction that introduces one be used for introducing the other?

Thanks.

Comment: clause in my post is a grammatical term.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for teaching me.

Comment: Can you say given your Latin studies, that the grammatical term proviso clause is restricted to grammar in Latin only, out of curiosity? I'm not unfamiliar with English grammar, and I can't seem to find an example in English.

Comment: I cannot.......

Comment: This looks like a question for [Latin SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/). Proviso clauses typically introduce conditional commitments, something is to happen provided that something is done. "The flowers will last, provided that they are watered". Conditional sentences have no such connotation, they give a condition of possibility that stands irrespective of anybody's actions. "If not watered the flowers will wither".

Comment: A if B is the same as A provided that B.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the Latin aside, and assuming we are using simple truth functional conditionals, there is no difference in the logic between "B if A" and "B provided A". Conditionals in English may be stated using lots of different words, e.g. supposing, assuming, were, had, should, unless, otherwise, provided, etc. Even the words 'and' and 'or' can be used to state conditionals, e.g. "buy me a drink and I'll be your friend", "hand over the money or I'll shoot".

There is a slight difference between the pragmatics of 'if' and 'provided'. In some cases they are indistinguishable, e.g. "If you are good, Santa will bring you a present", "Provided you are good, Santa will bring you a present". But in some cases, it is inappropriate to use 'provided', e.g. "If you eat all that chocolate you will be sick" sounds OK, but "Provided you eat all that chocolate you will be sick" sounds wrong in English. 'Provided' is typically not used when the main clause is something undesirable, whereas 'if' is more widely applicable.

Incidentally, your quote "the conditional clause states the condition that must occur in order for the main clause to occur" is either incorrect or misleadingly worded. With a conditional "if A then B", the conditional clause A is sufficient for the main clause B but not necessary. B may be true independently of whether A is true. (It would not be the first grammar book or website confusing "if A then B" with "if B then A".)